# Inserting sequence of values into single column

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I need to add one column to my table, which would look like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,...]
```

ie. sequence 1:5

I tried to use this code:

```
INSERT INTO table (name_of_new_column)
VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2.....)
```

But what I get is this error message:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

How can I solve this?

Comment: So you have only one column in table? What is your table structure?

Comment: What you try to acheave is to add many values on ONE field. If you have 2 fields, you have to add 2 values. You can't add many values to only one field

Comment: Thank you all for help. I shouldve just read manual which says "INSERT inserts new rows into an existing table". I followed your advices but got another error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax should be :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name_of_new_column)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)...
```

[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74272/1)